# YAMLException: incomplete explicit mapping pair

Tags: node.js, yaml, webpack

I can't figure out where my syntax is off. I've tried a hundred variations of this content. I'm using the yaml-loader from webpack. So, a javascript parser.

```
---
colors:
  - orange:
    100: "#hexcode"
    75: "#hexcode"
    50: "#hexcode"
    25: "#hexcode"
  - red:
    100: "#hexcode"
    75: "#hexcode"
    50: "#hexcode"
    25: "#hexcode"
```

Here's the full error:

```
    ERROR in ./~/json-loader!./~/yaml-loader!./data/colors.yaml
Module build failed: YAMLException: incomplete explicit mapping pair; a key node is missed at line 1, column 73:
     ... :\n    100: \"#hexcode\"\n    75: \"#hexcode\"\n
```

There's a carrot pointer at the `:` of `75:`

Comment: You need to post more about your problem.   Are you getting a parse error?   A structure you did not expect?   What are you seeing?

Comment: That said, a common trip-up is that yaml is whitespace-sensitive:  tabs and spaces are not interchangable at the start of lines, in particular, where indents are required.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @BadZen - it's a parse error (referenced in the title, now added in the body to be more explicit) - I've got an auto tab to space env set up. Maybe you can look at the new error report and see if anything rings a bell? Thanksl

Comment: While your YAML probably does not do what you want (because `orange` and the following lines are on the same level), it is definitely valid. If you get a parser error here, report it as bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately parsing YAML is a complicated business; so while this may be valid to some parsers (e.g. Ruby's `YAML` parses this just fine) it may not be valid to others.

It also depends on what sort of structure you need `colors` to be, at the moment Ruby expresses that as an array of objects:

```
{"colors"=>
  [
    {"orange"=>nil, 100=>"#hexcode", 75=>"#hexcode", 50=>"#hexcode", 25=>"#hexcode"}, 
    {"red"=>nil, 100=>"#hexcode", 75=>"#hexcode", 50=>"#hexcode", 25=>"#hexcode"}
  ]
}
```

where `orange` and `red` are undefined keys (which makes sense).

What you probably want is a nested object like so:

```
---
colors:
  orange:
      100: "#hexcode"
      # ...
  red:
      100: "#hexcode"
      # ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately that still doesn't work. I've edited the question with more details about the error. It's a javascript parser but I'm not really breaking the bank on "yaml creativity" - maybe the new edit shows something new?

Comment: How does Nick's suggestion not work? This seems to be the proper solution.

Comment: same parse error with that format. I've tried two different parsers. It might be some kind of bug.

Comment: Line ending issue? The error message reports that the error occurs at line 1, which doesn't have 73 chars. Try switching between CRLF and LF. (Both *must* be supported by a YAML implementation.)